# How to set up init-method for a bean when spring is configured by annotation driven?

Tags: spring, configuration, annotations, initialization, spring-roo

I use spring roo to build project and it's annotation driven, and there is no bean definition in XML file. All the configuration info is in *.aj file.

And now I want to set up an init method for a bean which don't have a default constructor (that bean is from the third party and it has a constructor with arguments, and I cannot remove them or give a default constructor to it.)

Is there anyone who can tell me how to do this, please?

The reason I want to do this is because I want to use `applicationContext.getBean("thatBeanName")` to dynamically get the bean and use it. Because the bean don't have a default constructor, I always get the error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.to.that.bean.<init>()` and this is why I want to add the init-method to the bean.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `@PostConstruct` as shown in below example. It is equivalent to `init-method="initialize()"`

```
@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    messages.put("English", "Welcome");
    messages.put("Deutsch", "Willkommen");
}
```

Comment: it is not equivalent IMHO @Bean(initMethod="init") is CORRECT
i would avoid using @PostConstruct as initMethod if possible.

Comment: @magulla Why's that?

Comment: @DoNuT see my reasoning here, put it in answer so 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46569019/1479668

Comment: that's wrong Yarram, postConstruct is not the same because initMethod is called after post construct and afterPropertiesSet methods

Answer (score 24):

```
@Bean(initMethod="init")
public MyBean getMyBean() {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Use this if you don't have access to the source of the bean you are trying to create.  Otherwise, use @PostConstruct.

Answer (score 4):

In spring container it is "init" method that being called the last,
@postconstruct called before afterPropertiesSet. so it is safer if someone miss use.
"Multiple lifecycle mechanisms configured for the same bean, with different initialization methods, are called as follows:

> 1.Methods annotated with @PostConstruct
>
> 2.afterPropertiesSet() as defined by the InitializingBean callback interface
>
> 3. A custom configured init() method
>      [https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-lifecycle-callbacks][1]

**Although**, today I would prefer to be more Spring independent and use either @Postconstract, or even configure default init method recognition. to have only meaningful method name indicate that it should be used for initialization - clear from frameworks, clear from annotations.

Answer (score 3):

As @Pangea has put in , [@PostConstruct](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) is the best choice. You could also implement initializingBean and do the initialization in afterPropertiesSet method .Check [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) for this approach.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that there have been multiple answers trying to solve the problem. But with the *newly* introduced `@Configuration` which is popularly used within *Spring Boot*. Things are changed a little bit.

If you are using `@Bean` annotation in `@Configuration` annotated class like:

```
@Configuration
class FooClass {
    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```

If you want to use an automatically called method on the bean instance during initialization, you have two options below:

#### Option1:

```
@Configuration
class FooClass {
    @Bean(initMethod="init")
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar();
    }
}
```

#### Option2:

```
@Configuration
class FooClass {
    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.init();
        return bar;
    }
}
```

**BUT**, as is explain in `@Bean` Java Doc here:

```
 /**

     * The optional name of a method to call on the bean instance during initialization.

     * Not commonly used, given that the method may be called programmatically directly

     * within the body of a Bean-annotated method.

     * The default value is {@code ""}, indicating no init method to be called.

     */
```

The second is regarded as a better answer. See link [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html#initMethod--)